# ThreadPooler in Spring 2.5.6

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

My application uses Spring 2.5.6. I have a service that creates explicit threads for some specific task. Triggering of this service call happens through quartz time scheduler.

Question :

While executing service calls, i want to use some sort of thread pooler that can return me thread instances. Is there any implementations that i can use in Spring?

Comment: Why do you need actual Thread instances? What use is that? Don't you just need to execute tasks in the background?

Comment: well, its a bit complicated to explain. but i ll try. Quartz initiates a trigger that a) accumulates candidates for certain tasks b) calls service for each of those candidates. My service i) makes a call to an external system and ii) does some stuff @ my end in order to complete its execution. I create threads for part "i)". And now want to use a pooler for it.

Comment: Yes, but why does this require access to `Thread` objects, rather than using something easier to use like an `Executor`?

Comment: i need to set timeouts on each call... Executor, i assume, does not allow me to.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use the `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` class.

You can also use Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` class. Both classes can be configured as ordinary Spring beans.

And since it's just normal Spring bean, you can code against it.

If you upgrade to Spring 3, you have better concurrency support. You can for example declaratively execute a method in an async process with the `@Async` annotation.

I have written a tutorial about how you can use thread pooling with Spring 3 [here](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/08/spring-asynchronous-support/).

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using a [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html#simpleThreadPoolTaskExecutor)?  You can easily configure this using spring, [from the doco](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor-usage):

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

But i have another issue...
Somehow it is not accepting the cofig which i am setting to...

```
<bean id="threadPoolTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="100" />
    <property name="daemon" value="true" />
    <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="54000" /> 
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
    <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="ThreadPoolTaskExecutor For Cron" />
</bean>
```

but somehow the things are set to the default ones..

pool size : 0
core pool size : 50
max pool size : 100
deamon : false
active count : 0
keep alive seconds : 60
thread prifix : taskExecutor-